# Filtering Inner Collection in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have Teams and each Team is holding Products Collection and Products Holding Branches Collection.
Each of the above Entity is having a Field say: IsActive
I want to retrieve Teams, Products, Branches which are Active Only ( IsActive=true).

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<Team> query = dbContext.Teams.AsNoTracking();
query = query.Include("Products");
query = query.Include("Products.Branches");

//Filtering Active Teams
queryMod = queryMod.Where(b => b.IsActive == active.Value);

//Filtering Active Products
queryMod = queryMod.Where(b => b.Products.Where(c => c.IsActive == active.Value).All(d=>d.IsActive==active.Value));

//Filtering Active Branches 
queryMod = queryMod.Where(b => b.Products.All(c => c.Branches.All(d=>d.IsActive == active.Value) && c.IsActive == active.Value));
```

But looks like this is not working as expected.
What is the correct form of using this statement to filter the Inner groups 
Any direction or help is appreciated!.

Thanks

Comment: Use Any instead of Where in the inner query (on the penultimate query).

Comment: Yes, i tried to use Any, All in place of where, but did not had any luck.